# What font is this?

Tags: font-identification

[image]

This font is used in [Pharell Williams' "It Girl" video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pPZDBF0kei0).

I have tried using the online font identification tools, but they seem to be having trouble because of the colored background and text.

Comment: I'd peck around dafont.com using terms like 'bubble' or 'balloon'

Comment: [Similar font](http://www.dafont.com/bubbleubblekickssomeass.font?text=Pharrel+Williams)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think these are fonts, but rather hand-rendered letter forms. Here is why:

The lowercase "a" is different in Pharrell and Williams.

[image]

The two lowercase "l"s used in Pharrell (while identical to each other) are different than the two used in Williams.

[image]

And finally, the "i"s used in It and Girl are also just a tiny bit different from each other.

[image]

Comment: good sleuthing!

Comment: Oh wow, I hadn't thought of that. Good eye.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe next time you can try out these online font finders.
http://www.fontsquirrel.com/matcherator
https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/